# Prove $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: group-theory

In trying to understand why there are two sets of groups of order 4.

I know that there exists the Vierergruppe of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and the group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ but I do not understand why they are not isomorphic

Comment: $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ has no element of order $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume by contradiction there is an isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_4\to\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2.$

So if $\langle x \rangle $ generates $\mathbb{Z}_4$, then- the order of $x$ is 4. $\varphi(x) = g$ and $g\in \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ so the order of $g$ is either 2 or 1. therefore, $\varphi(x^2) = \varphi(x)\varphi(x)=gg = e$. but $x^2 \neq e$. therefore $\varphi$ is not one-to-one, and therefore not an isomorphism.